# Reading data and store each col in different array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i have n cols and m rows in a specific file how i can but each col in a different array ?
 *the number of rows and cols are changeable

```
        String readline = null;
        readline = read.readLine();
        String[] getlength = readline.split(" ");
        cols = getlength.length;

        while (readline != null) {
            readline = read.readLine();
            rows++;
        }
        // Array of data 
        int[][] data = new int[rows][cols];
        // New bufferedReader to put the cursor on the top of the file
        read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("1.txt"));
        // for loop to skip first three rows
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            read.readLine();
        }

        // to set the file Data  into the array
        String line = null;
        line = read.readLine();
        do {

            readData = line.split(" ");

            for (int j = 0; j < readData.length; j++) {
                data[indexx][j] = Integer.parseInt(readData[j]);
            }

            indexx++;
            line = read.readLine();
        } while (line != null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the number of columns in the table you are reading you should use an `ArrayList`. One possible way would be:

```
[...]
ArrayList result = new ArrayList<int[]>();
line = read.readLine();
do {
  readData = line.split(" ");
  int[] row = new int[readData.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < readData.length; i++) {
    row[i] = Integer.parseInt(readData[i]);
  }
  result.add(row);
} while (line != null);
```

Now if you need your result as an array you can do the following conversion:

```
int[] data = result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
```